# React with AWS - Error: html-webpack-plugin could not minify the generated output

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

When I deploy the contents of my build folder to my S3 bucket, I get this error below each time. The app builds fine when I run npm build, and it works when I run npm start. I created another app following the generic create-react-app tutorial, and that worked fine when I deployed it to AWS.

````
  Error: html-webpack-plugin could not minify the generated output.
  In production mode the html minifcation is enabled by default.
  If you are not generating a valid html output please disable it manually.
  You can do so by adding the following setting to your HtmlWebpackPlugin config:
  |
  |    minify: false
  |
  See https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options for details.
  For parser dedicated bugs please create an issue here:
  https://danielruf.github.io/html-minifier-terser/
  Parse Error: React App

- htmlparser.js:244 new HTMLParser
    [Accrescent]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlparser.js:244:13
  
  - htmlminifier.js:993 minify
    [Accrescent]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlminifier.js:993:3
  
  - htmlminifier.js:1354 Object.exports.minify
    [Accrescent]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlminifier.js:1354:16
  
  - index.js:1013 HtmlWebpackPlugin.minifyHtml
    [Accrescent]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:1013:46
  
  - index.js:429 HtmlWebpackPlugin.postProcessHtml
    [Accrescent]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:429:40
  
  - index.js:254 
    [Accrescent]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:254:25
  
  - task_queues.js:93 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5```
````